# How do I write a function that counts consecutive letters in a string that are identical

Tags: c++

searchingWrite a  function **conseclets** which will receive one string as parameter. The function will determine all cases in which two or more consecutive letters in the string are identical.

For example, if "Barrymoore" is sent to the function, it will say that there are consecutive letters r and o in the string. But if "Bush" is sent to the function, it will say there are no two consecutive letters which are the same.

Here is my code the problem with it is when I put in a letter to find it finds it but not consecutively

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()

{
    char searching='\0';
    string name=" ";
    int counter =0;

    cout<<"Enter a name  : "<<endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<"Which letter would you like to count the number of times it appears: "<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    for(int i=0; i<name.length();i++){
        if(sentence[i]==searching){

        counter++;

        }
    }
    cout<<"The letter " << searching << " appears "<< counter << " times ";

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: When creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's usually a plus if it actually *compiles* (unless you ask about a build error). Don't just re-type code into the question. copy and paste it instead.

Comment: As for your problem, try to solve it on paper first. Write down the input string on paper, and try to figure out there how to count consecutive characters.

Comment: Do you need an algorithm or do you already have one? If you need one, ask for it specifically. If you have one, explain it and show us your attempt to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char a[30];
int i,c=0;
printf("enter a string\n");
gets(a);
for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
{
if(a[i]==a[i+1])
{
    printf("%c is consecutive\n",a[i]);
    c++;
}
}
if(c==0)
{
printf("No consecutive letters");   
}
return 0;
}
// Check this. This is proper code for your problem.
```

Comment: thank you Sudhanshu but my class never learned #include <stdio.h> or <stdlib.h> or <string.h> we only learned #include<string>. Also if i enter a string like "bush" that has no consecutive letters i should get a message saying no consecutive letters, so i should include a if else statement then correct?

Comment: In C++ you should include standard C functionality from the `<c*>` headers, and scope them inside `std::`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation making use of the standard algorithm library. I've called "runs" the sequences of identical consecutive letters. The algorithm is not necessarily optimal, but it's simple and that matters too.

```
void conseclets(std::string const &str) {
    // Keep the end of the string, and point i to the first run's beginning
    auto e = end(str), i = std::adjacent_find(begin(str), e);

    if(i == e)
        std::cout << "No repetition.\n";
    else do {
        // Locate the end of the run (that is, the first different letter)
        auto next = std::find_if(i, e, [&i](auto const &c){ return c != *i; });

        // Print out the match
        std::cout << "Letter " << *i << " is repeated "
                  << std::distance(i, next) << " times.\n";

        // Skip to the next run's beginning
        i = std::adjacent_find(next, e);

    // Do so until we reached the end of the string
    } while(i != e);
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d53095b2b3497cf4)

Comment: Thanks man but this is way to advanced for me im only in introduction to c++ half this stuff like auto and adjacent:: find have never heard of them but thanks anyway appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

template<typename I, typename O> O repeats(I b, I e, O result){
    while(b!=e){
        bool once = true;
        I p = b;
        while(++b!=e && *p==*b){
            if(once){
                *result++ = *p;
                once = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {    
    string name = "Barrymoore";
    string res;
    repeats(begin(name), end(name), back_inserter(res));
    cout << "There are " << res.size() << " consecutive letters :" << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

though there are several ways to do it, just modifying yours optimally to achieve whats required here :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    char searching = '\0';
    string name = " ";
    int counter = 0;
    cout << "Enter a name  : " << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Which letter would you like to count the number of times it appears: " << endl;
    cin >> searching;
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if (name[i] == searching) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << "The letter " << searching << " appears " << counter << " times ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that "Hello, World!" is not at all what I desired to add :P :P :D